# How to prevent JsSIP asking for microphone access?

Tags: webrtc, jssip

I have to create a webrtc application (using JsSIP) where the goal is only to be able to listen to the remote call.

I am searching a way to setup my JsSIP sip stack / sip session to disable the local microphone.
I want to make it that the browser doesn't ask for access to the microphone, as it is not needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Currently, it is not possible with JsSip, and to make it clear it is not possible on modern secure browsers.
The problem is not with JsSip but with the browsers, for security reasons browsers don't allow websites to access the microphone without the user permission as hackers can use this to monitor user conversations without their permission.

But I have observed from using JsSip on some browsers, the browser will automatically allow the user after permission has been giving to your site for the first time, ( at least on google chrome).

**Solution**
If there is a need to allow a smooth transition of audio permission-giving to your website, you should prompt your users to enable their browsers to always allow the permission. This has worked on chrome mobile and Firefox web browsers. Permissions are giving automatically.

I hope this solves your problem. you can contact me for anything with JsSip, ready to help you.

Comment: No, I don't want to use the microphone, at all, because the call is unidirectional, I want the web browser to reproduce the sound it receive, but I don't want it to be able to send sound, I don't need it and as such, this should remove the permissions popup.

Comment: I don't think JsSIP is able to do that for you. Generally, you can disable audio to see if this works.
use this
`var options = {
  'eventHandlers': eventHandlers,
  'extraHeaders': [ 'X-Foo: foo', 'X-Bar: bar' ],
  'mediaConstraints': {'audio': false, 'video': true} // Main edit.
};`

Comment: Disabling audio will indeed disable the prompt for access to the microphone, but will also prevent me to hear anything (and I don't need video)